# How to have the output sorted by the column numbers of the table?

Tags: sql, oracle, sorting

Here is my current sql to output tables that contains both "SERVICE_ID" and "SERVICE_NAME" columns.

```
select T1.column_name ||','||T2.column_name, T1.table_name 
from all_tab_columns T1, all_tab_columns T2
where T1.column_name = 'SERVICE_ID' and T2.column_name = 'SERVICE_NAME' 
and T1.table_name = T2.table_name and T1.owner = T2.owner;
```

Question I have is how do I have the output sorted by the "T1.table_name", that whichever table has the least number of total columns, output first ?

Comment: Hello welcome to StackOverflow, next time try to provide a 
  [**SqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5368b/6) with a schema and some data so we can understand the problem better and give you an answer 
   much faster – Also please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
   And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please include your rdbms, a sample data and desire output.

Comment: I added the Oracle tag, because `all_tab_columns` just screams "oracle".

Answer (score 0):

You can also write your query using conditional aggregation.  Then a `having` clause can get the tables with the two columns, and you can order by the ones with the most columns first:

```
select 'SERVICE_ID, SERVICE_NAME', t.table_name
from all_tab_columns t
group by t.table_name
having sum(case when t.column_name in ('SERVICE_ID', 'SERVICE_NAME') then 1 else 0 end) = 2
order by count(*) DESC;
```

Note that I hard-coded the column names in the `SELECT`.  You could also do that in your version.

Comment: Thanks for the quick help !